# Getting lot of errors while building custom tab bar app with XCode 4.2

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, xcode4.2

I just downloaded the new XCode and built my app which has a custom tab bar drawing included.

I got a whole lot of errors like:

```
  <Error>: CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0
  <Error>: CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0
  <Error>: CGContextGetCompositeOperation: invalid context 0x0
  <Error>: CGContextSetCompositeOperation: invalid context 0x0
  <Error>: CGContextFillRects: invalid context 0x0
  <Error>: CGContextSetCompositeOperation: invalid context 0x0
  <Error>: CGContextSetRGBFillColor: invalid context 0x0
  <Error>: CGContextFillRects: invalid context 0x0
```

and so on. How do I resolve them? My app is not launching as well.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, that you do drawing things in

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{

    NSLog(@"##### DRAW RECT #####");
    [super drawRect:rect];
    CGContextRef context    = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(); // This is important string
    // Drawing code
}
```